# Mockery mock not returning specified value

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mockery

I'm using Mockery in my Laravel project to mock the User Eloquent model and test a route.

This is how I test the `/api/user/activate` route:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class ActivateTest extends TestCase
{
    private $userMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->userMock = Mockery::mock('App\User');

        Session::start();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testActivate()
    {
        $this->userMock->shouldReceive('where->first')->once()->andReturn('test');
        $this->userMock->shouldReceive('activate')->once();

        $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/user/activate', [
            'activationToken' => '838jfjnvu83u3',
            '_token' => csrf_token()
        ]);

        // This will be displayed in the PHPunit output
        print_r($response->getContent());

        $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `andReturn('test')` doesn't seem to work. The PHPunit result is:

```
F{"error":{"message":null,"statusCode":404}}

Time: 276 ms, Memory: 15.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) ActivateTest::testActivate
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.
```

This is the content of the `activate()` in the `UserController`:

```
public function activate(Request $request)
{
    $activation = $request->input();

    $user = $this->user->where('activationToken', $activation['activationToken'])->first();

    if(!$user) return $this->respondNotFound($user);

    try
    {
        $user->activate($activation['password']);
    }
    catch(ModelException $e)
    {
        return $this->respondInternalError($e->errorMessages());
    };

    return $this->respondCreated('Account activated.');
}
```

The problem is that `$user` in the controller is `null` because the mock is not returning `test` (in that case the condition would evaluate to true and I wouldn't get a 404 response).

**Edit:**

I also tried using PHPunit mocking but it wasn't successful:

```
$this->userMock = $this->getMockBuilder('App\User')->setMethods(['where', 'first', 'activate'])->getMock();

$this->userMock->expects($this->once())->method('where')->willReturn($this->userMock);
$this->userMock->expects($this->once())->method('first')->willReturn('test');
$this->userMock->expects($this->once())->method('activate');
```

Comment: I'm not very known with Mockery yet, but i think that the `where->first` is not possible because it's not a valid function. The function/attr called on the `user` object is `where` and that returns a object which you call `first()` on..

Comment: Well looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748005/mocking-a-call-with-chained-methods-and-arguments) it looks like I can do that.

Comment: I don't see any `..->shouldReceive('where->first')` in the provided question. Only the stub answer has something about it but thats an extension or something.

Comment: _You can do shouldReceive('select->where->runQuery->fetch') if you do not care about the arguments._

Anyway, analyzing the code I noticed what could be causing the issue. Probably the fact that the function `first()` is not actually an eloquent model function is causing the issue.

Comment: Ah thx, didn't know that chaining was possible. Will try that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by `->first()` since it's not a method existing neither on the `Eloquent` or `User` classes.

To solve it I created a new `UserRepository` and injected it as a dependency in the controller constructor.

```
class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @param $activationToken
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function whereActivationToken($activationToken)
    {
        return $this->user->where('activationToken', $activationToken)->first();
    }
}
```

Injection in the `UserController`:

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
```

And this is how the test `PostActivateTest` class looks like now:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class PostActivateTest extends TestCase
{
    private $user;
    private $userRepositoryMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user               = Mockery::mock('App\User');
        $this->userRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock('Repository\Database\UserRepository');
        $this->app->instance('App\User', $this->user);
        $this->app->instance('Bloom\BloomCRM\Repository\Database\UserRepository', $this->userRepositoryMock);

        Session::start();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testActivate()
    {
        $this->userRepositoryMock->shouldReceive('whereActivationToken')->once()->andReturn($this->user);
        $this->user->shouldReceive('activate')->once();

        $this->call('POST', '/api/user/activate', [
            'activationToken' => '838jfjnvu83u3',
            'password' => 'test',
            '_token' => csrf_token()
        ]);

        $this->assertResponseStatus(201);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to mock an object.  You need to get that mocked object to be injected into the class which contains that `activate()` function.

You can do that in your `setUp()` function as well.  Try adding this...

```
$this->app->instance('App/User', $this->userMock);
```

That will tell Laravel when you want to inject an instance of `App/User`, to inject the mock object you just created instead.